# Customize Gnome-Do's default action order

Tags: 10.10, scripts, gnome-do

I'm using Gnome-Do with the "Files and Folders v2.5" plugin. I set it to read my *.scripts* folder, so that I might run my personal scripts from Gnome-Do. The only problem is that Gnome-Do's standard action for shell scripts is to open them instead of running them. That forces me to Tab and scroll-down every time. **How can I change Gnome-Do's standard action?**

*An example for clarity:*
I have a *foo.sh* executable file inside my *.scripts* folder. When I type *foo* inside Gnome-Do, it correctly selects the file and offers the *Open* action. I then have to Tab, press Down, and hit Enter to select the *Run* action instead. I would the *Run* action to be first on the list.

**Alternatively, a more appropriate way to integrate Gnome-Do with personal scripts would be fine as well.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not *directly* possible in Do, but it does have a capability to learn what you mean.  The default action for any item is always the action you've used most frequently out of the possible actions for that item.

So, one way of getting what you want would be to just use the `run` action a lot from Do.

Another way would be to inform Do that your script is an “application” that's runnable, like Firefox or Evolution or such.  Do determines the list of applications by searching for `.desktop` files in the standard locations.  One of these locations is `~/.local/share/applications`.  So, if you create a `foo.desktop` file looking something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Foo desktop frobinator
GenericName=Desktop frobinator
Comment=Awesomeate your desktop!
Exec=/home/raof/.scripts/foo.sh
Icon=shotwell
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Graphics;Photography;GNOME;GTK;
```

you'll get a “Foo desktop frobinator” runnable item in Do.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the first part. I've tried running my script over a dozen times and gnome-do still offers to open it for me by default, even though I only opened it once or twice.

Comment: I really like the second option, though it'll be annoying to do that for each of the scripts, I think I'll go with it.

Comment: The “default action” code is a bit limited.  It's not how many times you've selected “run” vs “open” on the “foo” item, it's how many times you've selected “open” vs “run”, regardless of the item.  It's one of the remaining areas of significant suck in Do.